# Run a Liquid filter from a Jekyll plugin

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

Liquid has two filters named `newline_to_br` and `escape`.

I'm working on a Jekyll plugin that needs to run a string through those filters. Rather than install a separate gem which does this, or write my own code for it, is there any way to call those filters directly from inside of the plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those filters can become available with the line `include Liquid::StandardFilters`.

For example:

```
class PlaintextConverter
    include Liquid::StandardFilters
    def convert(content)
        content = escape(content)
        content = newline_to_br(content)
        content
    end
end
```

For a full list of functions that become available in this way, you can view [the source of `standardfilters.rb`](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/blob/master/lib/liquid/standardfilters.rb)